# server.transfer is not working with update panel

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm using Ajax Update panel, now i'm trying to transfer from one aspx page to another apsx page by using server.transfer , but it is giving error.

I have tried

```
Server.Transfer("User.aspx");
```

Comment: What error is it giving you?

Comment: error executing for child request User.apsx

Comment: <Triggers>
<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" />
</Triggers>

use this in .aspx page.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your update panel if you don't have it.

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnYourButtonId"/>
   </Triggers>
```

Remember to keep it asp:PostBackTrigger instead of asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger. Latter doesn't work with server.transfer.